# Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert. The client driver may require an upgrade

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I stuck up with this error for the last two days. I am new to node and MongoDB and because of this error, I could not proceed further.

Here is my code for reference.

```
const express = require('express');
//const app = express();

const mongoose = require('mongoose');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/playground')
.then(() => console.log('connected to mongoDB'))
.catch(err => console.log('could not connect')) 

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    tags: [String],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    isPublished: Boolean
});

const Course = mongoose.model('course', courseSchema);

async function createCourse(){
    const course = new Course({
        name: 'Angular Course',
        author: 'Node Learner',
        tags: [ 'Angular', 'backend'],
        isPublished: true
    });

    const result = await course.save();
    console.log(result);
}
createCourse();


 ok: 0,
  errmsg: 'Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal',
  code: 352,
  codeName: 'UnsupportedOpQueryCommand'
```

I browsed about this error and it always tells me to the client driver may require an upgrade.

My node.js version is the current stable version - 18.12.1.
My npm version is 8.19.2

I also checked my network connection and tried VPN too.

Comment: Did you try the update as advised by the error message?

Comment: you mean upgrade to nodejs? yes my current nodejs version is(18.12.1) @Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: The MongoDB driver: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb

Comment: Frustratingly, the error links to this page: `https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/release-notes/6.0-compatibility/#legacy-opcodes-removed` but does not include HOW to upgrade, but has a section on Downgrade Considerations. A bit of an oversight there I think. `$npm install mongodb` updated my version with no visible side effects.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was an old version of the `connect-mongodb-session` npm package. Check if you use it.

I fixed the error by upgrading `connect-mongodb-session` version 2.0.6 to the latest 3.1.1.

I have MongoDB 6.0.6 installed.

Answer (score 1):

To run the provided code successfully, please ensure that you have **MongoDB version 4.4** installed and the **Mongoose** library version **5.0.1**. These specific versions are recommended for compatibility with the code snippet you shared.

Answer (score 0):

The error is showing because of two reasons either mongoose version has become old or it has not been installed yet .
try installing mongoose again

`npm i mongoose`

Comment: It looks like that answer already exists

Answer (score 0):

I think your node is upgraded so try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the connection string

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your using **Windows**:

1. If you are using newer version like I did (v7.0.2), You should consider **downgrading** your MongoDB version to a compatible one, like `3.6.23`
2. Install `mongoose@5.0.1`
3. Remember to **update path** in **Environment variables**.
4. Run `mongod` in command prompt, and if it doesn't start, try again after **restarting** windows.
5. if in command prompt, you see `waiting for connections`, you are good to go

This is my exprience and how I solved it. Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

Try installing mongoose again

```
npm i mongoose
```